# Passing Stack to Function

Tags: c++, function, stack

So I'm playing around with stacks and I've filled one in my main function, but now I want to pass it to my other functions so I can traverse through it. I'm not sure what kind of data type to put into the prototype though so that it accepts it. Suggestions? Here's what I have:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "stack.h"

void displayStack(char &stackRef);

int main()
{
    Stack<char> stack;
    stack.push('a');
    stack.push('b');
    stack.push('c');

    return 0;
};

void displayStack(char starRef)
{
    // Cannot Get here - Errors!
};
```

It's telling me I have too many arguments and it doesn't match argument list.

Comment: Since the object you pass to the function is of type `Stack<char>`, it is most natural for the function to be declared as `void displayStack(Stack<char> &stackref)` (possibly add `const`). Also, the homework tag is deprecated, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
void displayStack(const Stack<char>& stack);
```

Answer (score 4):

The name `DisplayStack` indicates that the function only displays the stack, not changing it in any way. So then the argument can be a *reference to `const`*. However, the suffix `Stack` in the name is redundant since it is implied by the argument, so I’d do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "stack.h"

typedef Stack< char > CharStack;

void display( CharStack const& stack )
{
    // ... Display the stack
}

int main()
{
    CharStack stack;

    for( auto const ch : { 'a', 'b', 'c' } )
    {
        stack.push( ch );
    }
    display( stack );
}
```

Note that …

- The function has been moved *above* `main`. No silly pure declaration required then, less work. **DRY**: *Don't Repeat Yourself*.
- Incorrect semicolons after the function definitions, have been removed. Well, at least I think they’re incorrect. Whether they are or not, they’re totally superfluous.
- Superfluous `return 0;` in `main` has been removed, because that is *the default*. However, some programmers prefer to have it explicit.

On the downside, while the C++11 loop compiles nicely with g++ 4.7.2, it causes an Internal Compiler Error (**ICE**) with Visual C++ 11.0:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp
foo.cpp
foo.cpp(7) : warning C4100: 'stack' : unreferenced formal parameter
foo.cpp(16) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
foo.cpp(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
c1xx : fatal error C1063: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR
         Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
         Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

Oh well.

Do that your way. ;-)

Compiler bug [reported to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768644/internal-compiler-error-for-c-11-range-based-loop-with-range).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to modify contents of the stack inside the function:

```
void displayStack(const Stack<char> &starRef)
```

If you want to modify the contents of the stack inside the function:

```
void displayStack(Stack<char> &starRef)
```

Points to note:

- The *type* of the variable being passed must be the *type* you mention in function prototype.
- In C/C++, by default all arguments to function are passed *by copy*, i.e: A copy of the argument rather than the argument itself is passed to the function. The overhead is the copy. You *pass by reference* to avoid overhead of a copy of variable being passed.
- You use `const` qualifier on the argument if you want the passed variable to be immutable in the function.

Comment: _The type of the variable being passed must be the type you mention in function prototype._ -- Must it?

Comment: @jogojapan: Usually When you write a function prorotype Yes. You might also have implicit casting i.e: One conversion sequence the standard provides for overload resolution or Upcasting which will also work without exact type matching but the discussion here is about writing a function prortype and not the possibilities in general.

Answer (score 0):

Change your displayStack function to:

```
void displayStack(Stack<char> &stackRef)
```